# Manim: how to define a template for Text objects?

Tags: text, manim

I have to create many Text objects that differs only in the .text.

I tried

`newtext=templatetext.copy()`

`newtext1.text="Nuevo texto"`

`self.play(Write(newtext1))`

but after rendering I see the content (text) of `templatetext` instead of the content of `newtext1`.
what is wrong?